# Lifetime and associated types

Tags: rust, lifetime, associated-types

I have this enum:

```rust
enum Node<T> {
    Leaf(T),
    Children(Vec<Node<T>>),
}
```

And want to implement the `Iterator` trait for `Node`.
I created this struct and tried to implement the `IntoIterator` trait:

```rust
struct NodeIter<'a, T>{
    children: &'a [Node<T>],
    parent: Option<&'a Node<T>>,
}

impl<'a, T> IntoIterator for Node<T> {
    type Item = T;
    type IntoIter = NodeIter<'a, T>;

    fn into_iter(self) -> Self::IntoIter {
        todo!()
    }
}
```

I can not figure out the correct lifetime specifiers, I end up getting this error:

```
error[E0207]: the lifetime parameter `'a` is not constrained by the impl trait, self type, or predicates
  --> src/tree_my.rs:44:6
   |
44 | impl<'a, T> IntoIterator for Node<T> {
   |      ^^ unconstrained lifetime parameter
```

I am new to Rust and I am not sure if I am doing it wrong or if it is not possible. Because I have read about similar problems. The problem seems to have something to do with traits (`IntoIterator` in my case) and associated types. I also read something about GAT.

Maybe someone could explains this problem and how one would solve it.

[Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015&gist=63fcecf339006aec2214bff0a32ae462)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IntoIterator::into_iter` *consumes* its argument. This means that once you've called `node.into_iter()` the `node` no longer exists, but it looks like you want your `NodeIter` to keep references to `node` which is impossible since it's no longer around.

You will need to either change `NodeIter` to take ownership of the original `Node` so that `NodeIter` can keep the `Node` alive for as long as it needs it, or implement `IntoIter` for *references* to `Node` (which will consume the reference, but keep the original `Node` intact):

```
enum Node<T> {
    Leaf(T),
    Children(Vec<Node<T>>),
}

struct NodeIter<'a, T>{
    children: &'a [Node<T>],
    parent: Option<&'a Node<T>>,
}

impl<'a, T> Iterator for NodeIter<'a, T> {
    type Item = T;
    fn next (&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        todo!();
    }
}

impl<'a, T> IntoIterator for &'a Node<T> {
    type Item = T;
    type IntoIter = NodeIter<'a, T>;

    fn into_iter(self) -> Self::IntoIter {
        todo!()
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=0af3290dd6bfa563798dab7d998f9358)

Comment: That was surprisingly simple, I have not thought of that. Thanks for the explanation!